# Pegar dados das colunas de uma determinada linha com JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tenho uma tabela onde puxo os dados de todos os produtos que tenho cadastrado no banco de dados, mais ou menos assim:

```
codigo | descricao | valor | ...
----------------------------
123456 | produto 1 | 15,00 | ...
789123 | produto 2 | 65,90 | ...
```

Essa tabela fica oculta na pagina e serve para puxar os dados para dentro do carrinho de compras (sim, é uma tela de vendas). Ai que começa a brincadeira:

1. Preciso saber como fazer para, quando a pessoa digitar o código no campo de busca, ser feita uma pesquisa por aquele código na tabela.
2. Como fazer para retornar os valores das `<td>` relacionadas aquele código.
3. Como exibir esses dados na tela quando a pessoa clicar em "Adicionar ao carrinho".

Isso é para um trabalho de conclusão de curso, e é a unica parte que estou tendo mais dificuldades, se puderem me ajudar ficarei muito grato. Vlww

Segue o código (não vou colocar a pagina de conexao se não ficaria muito grande, mas deem um exemplo):

```js
$(function(){
             $(".dado-valor-total").mask('#.##0,00', { reverse: true });
         });
         
window.onload = calculaValor;
        
        var tabela = document.getElementById('tabelaOs');
        var linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        
        function calculaValor(){
            
            var totalVenda = 0;

            for(var i = 1 ; i <= linhas.length ; i++ ) {
                var qtd = document.querySelector("#qtdeItem"+[i]).value;
                var valorUnit = document.querySelector(".valor-unit"+[i]).textContent.replace(",",".");
                var valorTotal = document.querySelector(".valor-total"+[i]).textContent = parseFloat(valorUnit * qtd).toFixed(2).replace(".",",");
                totalVenda = parseFloat(totalVenda) + parseFloat(valorTotal.replace(",","."));
                document.querySelector(".dado-valor-total").textContent = totalVenda.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});
            }
        }
        
        for(var i = 1 ; i <= linhas.length ; i++ ) {
            var campoQtd = document.querySelector("#qtdeItem"+[i]);
            
            campoQtd.addEventListener('input',function(){
               calculaValor(); 
            });
        }

$(function(){
    fixarDescricao();
});


// vizualização da foto do produto
    function readURL(input, id) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('#'+id)
                .attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }  


// fixa descricao automaticamente
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".campo-formulario").on("keydown change", function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var siblings = elem.siblings();
    if (elem.val().length > 0) {
      siblings.addClass('descricao-fixa');
        $('.icon-form').removeClass('descricao-fixa');
    } else {
      siblings.removeClass('descricao-fixa');
        $('.icon-form').removeClass('descricao-fixa');
    }
  });
});


// fixar descrição do campo
function fixarDescricao() {
    var campo = $('.campo-formulario');
    var descricao = $('.descricao-campo');
    campo.on('input',function(){
        var descricaoAtual = $(this).parent().find('.descricao-campo');
       if($(this).val().length > 0){
           descricaoAtual.addClass('descricao-fixa');
       } else{
           descricaoAtual.removeClass('descricao-fixa');
       }
    }); 
    // remove a descrição fixa quando o botao reset é clicado
    var reset = $('input:reset');
    reset.on('click', function(){
        descricao.removeClass('descricao-fixa');
    });
}
```

```css
.abrir {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 10001;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s;
    display: flex;
}

body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.titulo {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.campo-tabela {
    width: 40px;
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.campo-tabela:focus {
    border: none;
}

.fa-laptop {
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: none;
}

.barra-lateral {
    transition: all .5s;
    width: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 80px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(30,30,30,.5);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.conteudo {
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.linha-adicionar-produto {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(50,50,50,.3);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.linha-conteudo-venda {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.thead-dark th {
    background-color: #333 !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

tr, td, th {
    color: #333;
}

.tabela-itens-venda {
    width: 69%;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 380px);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 380px);
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(50,50,50,.3);
}

.informacoes-venda {
    width: 29%;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 380px);
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(50,50,50,.3);
}

.linha-resumo-venda {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 30px 30px 30px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.conteudo-resumo-venda {
    height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(50,50,50,.3);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.foto-produto {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(50,50,50,.3);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.foto-produto a img {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.pesquisa-produto {
    width: calc(100% - 95px);
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.produto {
    width: calc(100% - 480px);
    min-width: 280px;
}

.qtde {
    width: 200px;
}

input, select {
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: 'Texto';
    color: #222;
    font-size: 105%;
    background: none;
    z-index: 3;
    background: #fff;
}

.formulario-informacoes-venda input, .formulario-informacoes-venda select {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container-campo {
    position: relative;
}

.descricao-campo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    transition: all .2s;
    cursor: text;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}

.descricao-fixa {
    top: -10px;
    left: 8px;
    transition: all .2s;
    z-index: 3;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus ~ .descricao-campo , select:focus ~ .descricao-campo {
    top: -10px;
    left: 8px;
    transition: all .2s;
    z-index: 3;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: dodgerblue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus , select:focus {
    border: 2px solid dodgerblue; 
}

#btn-pesquisa-produto {
    display: none;
}

.btn-cadastro {
    width: 250px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Titulos';
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 110%;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}

.btn-pesquisa-produto-label:hover {
    transform: translateY(0px);
}

.btn-pesquisa-produto-label {
    background: forestgreen;
}

.btns-acao-venda {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.btn-finalizar-venda {
    background: forestgreen;
}

.btn-cancelar-venda {
    background: darkred;
}

.valor-total-venda {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.titulo-valor-total {
    font-family: 'titulos';
    color: #333;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.dado-valor-total {
    font-family: 'titulos';
    color: forestgreen;
    font-size: 250%;
}

.fa-arrow-circle-right {
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.fa-edit, .fa-trash {
    color: #333;
}

.fa-edit:hover {
    color: forestgreen;
}

.fa-trash:hover {
    color: darkred;
}

.icon-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: dodgerblue;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-mobile {
    margin-top: 80px;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 30px;
    display: none;
}

.info-mobile {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.figure-info {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.principal-info-mobile {
    font-family: 'titulos';
    font-size: 300%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.desc-info-mobile {
    font-size: 110%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
    .titulo-valor-total, .dado-valor-total {
        font-size: 180%;
    }
    
    .btn-cadastro {
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    .tabela-itens-venda {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .informacoes-venda {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* tira o sublinhado dos links */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Texto';
    position: relative;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
}

.botoes-cadastro-funcionario {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.btn-cadastro {
    width: 250px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Titulos';
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-right: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.btn-cadastro:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}

.btn-cadastro:hover {
    transition: all .5s;
    transform: translateY(2px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
    .barra-lateral {
        width: 0;
    }
    
    .fa-laptop {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .abrir {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .titulo {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    .conteudo {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .quadros-aviso {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .box-aviso {
        width: 48%;
        margin-bottom: 3%;
    }
    
    .os-concluidas {
        display: flex;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    .titulo-tabela {
        background: none;
        color: #333;
        text-shadow: none;
        font-size: 200%;
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .titulo-tabela::before {
        content: '-';
        color: dodgerblue;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .titulo-tabela::after {
        content: '-';
        color: dodgerblue;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 626px) {
    .box-aviso {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 3%;
        padding: 15px 35px;
    }
    
    .btn-venda {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .fa-bell {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .icon-mobile.fa-bell {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .head {
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .box-search {
        top: 80px;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .footer {
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .icons-footer {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
    
    .copyright {
        order: 3;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 90%;
        color: #333;
    }
    
    .area-icons-mobile {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .menu li a:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid #444;
    }
    
    .conteudo {
        padding: 30px 15px;
    }
    
    .table {
        font-size: 90%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- <%@page import="model.Produto"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="ISO8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Saphyra® - Registrar Venda</title>
        <!-- folhas de estilo css -->
        <link href="css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/vendas.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- incorpora todo o conteudo do site -->
        <section class="container">
            

            <main class="main">
                <main class="conteudo">
                    <section class="linha-adicionar-produto">
                        <figure class="foto-produto">
                            <a href="img/package.png" rel="lightbox"><img src="img/package.png" title="Foto do Produto"></a>
                        </figure>
                        <form action="" class="pesquisa-produto">
                            <div class="container-campo produto">
                                <input type="text" class="campo-formulario" id="produto">
                                <label for="produto" class="descricao-campo">Escaneie ou digite o código do produto</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container-campo qtde">
                                <input type="number" class="campo-formulario" id="qtde">
                                <label for="qtde" class="descricao-campo">Qtde.</label>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" id="btn-pesquisa-produto">
                            <label class="btn-cadastro btn-pesquisa-produto-label" for="btn-pesquisa-produto"><div>adicionar ao carrinho</div></label>
                        </form>
                    </section>
                    <section class="linha-conteudo-venda">
                        <section class="tabela-itens-venda table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Descrição</th>
                                        <th>Qtde.</th>
                                        <th>R$ Unit.</th>
                                        <th>R$ Total</th>
                                        <th>Opções</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="tabelaOs">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>Formatação Sistema Operacional</td>
                                        <td><input type="number" min="1" class="campo-tabela" id="qtdeItem1" name="qtdeItem" value="6"></td>
                                        <td class="valor-unit1">60,00</td>
                                        <td class="valor-total1"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>2</td>
                                        <td>Formatação Sistema Operacional</td>
                                        <td><input type="number" min="1" class="campo-tabela" id="qtdeItem2" name="qtdeItem" value="2"></td>
                                        <td class="valor-unit2">17,65</td>
                                        <td class="valor-total2"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>3</td>
                                        <td>Formatação Sistema Operacional</td>
                                        <td><input type="number" min="1" class="campo-tabela" id="qtdeItem3" name="qtdeItem" value="4"></td>
                                        <td class="valor-unit3">60,00</td>
                                        <td class="valor-total3"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </section>
                        <section class="informacoes-venda">
                            
                            
                            
                            <!-- tabela invisivel para armazenar os dados dos produtos 
            
            <table id="tabela-invisivel" style="display:none">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>idproduto</th>
                        <th>codigo</th>
                        <th>descricao</th>
                        <th>categoria</th>
                        <th>qtde_estoque</th>
                        <th>qtde_minima</th>
                        <th>qtde_maxima</th>
                        <th>valor_custo</th>
                        <th>valor_venda</th>
                        <th>status</th>
                        <th>marca</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <jsp:useBean class="model.Produto" id="produto"/>
                <tbody>
                    
                    <c:forEach var="c" items="${produto.lista}">
                        
                    <tr>
                        <td>${c.idproduto}</td>
                        <td>${c.codigo_interno}</td>
                        <td>${c.descricao}</td>
                        <td>${c.categoria}</td>
                        <td>${c.qtde_estoque}</td>
                        <td>${c.qtde_minima}</td>
                        <td>${c.qtde_maxima}</td>
                        <td>${c.valor_custo}</td>
                        <td>${c.valor_venda}</td>
                        <td>
                            <c:if test="${c.status==1}">Ativo</c:if>
                            <c:if test="${c.status==2}">Inativo</c:if>
                        </td>
                        <td>${c.marca.nome}</td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    </c:forEach>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
                            
                            
                    -->        
                            
                        </section>
                    </section>
                    <section class="linha-resumo-venda">
                        <section class="conteudo-resumo-venda">
                            <section class="valor-total-venda">
                                <label class="titulo-valor-total">valor total da venda <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></label>
                                <p class="dado-valor-total"></p>
                            </section>
                            <section class="btns-acao-venda">
                                <label class="btn-cadastro btn-cancelar-venda"><div>cancelar venda</div></label>
                                <label class="btn-cadastro btn-finalizar-venda"><div>finalizar venda</div></label>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </section>
                </main>
            </main>
        </section>
        
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/abre-caixa-pesquisa.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cadastro-funcionario.js"></script>
    <script src="lightbox/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correção:

Como fazer para retornar os valores das COLUNAS relacionadas aquele código.

Comment: Acho que podes fazer isso com ajax. Você cria um evento clique que ao clicar no botão, então você pega o value daquele campo <td> da tabela e envia esse valor para o seu arquivo que faz a consulta no banco de dados, no arquivo de consulta você utiliza esse valor como condição do where no select. Por fim, retorna o valor da consulta, pega no done(retorno) do ajax e exibe o que você quiser na tela. (Foi uma explicação bem genérica, não dá pra explicar muito sem ver o seu código).

Comment: Boaa, vou colocar o codigo da pagina pra vc dar uma olhada. Eu to usando JSP

Comment: Não deu pra entender muito bem o que vc quer fazer, que coluna é essa? que código é esse? Seria melhor fazer um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)